# Steps to develop Asterisk Android Client with GSM Codec

Tags: android, voip, sip, asterisk, gsm

I am trying to develop a **Asterisk Android Client**. My preferred codec is **GSM**. I have downloaded SIPDroid source code and some other helping projects. 
But since I am totally new on this area, I am not sure where to start from.

Here is what I am trying to do at starting.

1. Record sound
2. Convert that sound to GSM RTP packet
3. Play that codec sound
4. Stream that GSM RTP Packet
5. Integrate SIP Session with the App

***I have one Android device (HTC Wildfire). Is it possible to test these steps from simulator to my set using Wi-Fi network?***

**Please give me an appropriate steps/algorithm on which I can develop the client App. 

It'll be great if someone give me some tips to use the existing projects.**
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the codec available? I doubt that anyone else is running GSM via RTP, so you are aiming for something proprietary.

Comment: @Bernd: GSM is free. thats why I am planning to use that. Any suggestion or alternative please?

Comment: Is the GSM codec you are referring to GSM HR/FR/EFR or G.711?

Comment: I am referring GSM HR (Half Rate I guess)

Comment: I though SipDroid supports the GSM codec already? And asterisk supports SIP, obviously.

Comment: I need to make the app only compatible for GSM Codec since some other codec has patent issues .So can't use SIPDroid. I guess i need to remove the other codec files and put only the GSM. what do you think?

Comment: SIPDroid is open source. It can not be used as Closed source projects. And i heard that architecture of SIPdroid is also under license. So, can't use that structure also.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a friend with an android phone to install SIPDroid, and it does support the GSM codec.

Comment: I only want to support the GSM part..so I guess i need to delete the other codec files from my project and make it error free. :) what do you think?

Comment: SIPDroid is open source. It can not be used as Closed source projects. And i heard that architecture of SIPdroid is also under license. So, can't use that structure also.

Comment: Yes, it's GPL, do not copy if you do not plan to adhere to the terms of the GPL.